# Pass credentials along to new WebRequest

Tags: authentication, credentials

I am making a page in SharePoint that is used to proxy other content in SharePoint. The user is authenticated at the time they hit this proxy page, but I am getting an Unauthorized Access error.

The page has the following code behind:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(urlToProxy);
request.Method = "GET";
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; //This isn't working, apparently
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
```

My first thought was to use the credentials from the incoming `WebRequest`, but this is an `HttpRequest` and doesn't seem to have the `Credentials` property.

Does anyone know how I can pass the user's existing logged in credentials to this outgoing `HttpWebRequest`?

Comment: Is this NTLM, Kerberos or Claims?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are facing the infamous double-hop issue.  In a nutshell, with NTLM you are authenticated to the server, but your credentials cannot be used by the server to access other servers.

Here is a good MSDN blog post explaining it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/besidethepoint/archive/2010/05/09/double-hop-authentication-why-ntlm-fails-and-kerberos-works.aspx

Basically you either have to use a service account (one you can access the credentials for in your code, storing them in the web.config or in the Secure Store Service) or use a different authentication method that lets you pass the credentials (i.e. kerberos).

Comment: Ok, so to get around that, I'm now trying to hardcode specific credentials just for this proxy page. I'm trying do  `request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(@"username", "password"){Domain = "domain"}` but this isn't working. Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: You might try creating a Credential Cache that you add your credentials to.  See the end of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2004/07/28/199706.aspx for an example.

Comment: CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
        cache.Add(new Uri("http://example.com"), "Negotiate", loginCredentials);
        cache.Add(new Uri("http://redirected.example.com"), "Negotiate", loginCredentials);
        request.Credentials = cache; - See more at: http://efreedom.com/Question/1-4918682/Building-CredentialCache-HttpWebRequestCredentials-Redirects-Uknown#sthash.axzmy5Kf.dpuf

Comment: This works for certain SharePoint pages, but unfortunately not the Office Web Apps, which is what I am trying to proxy. I'll post a solution if I find one. Thanks for your help.